# Name of the piano piece in the Argerich documentary "Bloody Daughter"

Tags: classical-music

I would like to know the name of the piano piece from the documentary "Bloody Daughter". The scene with the music starts 1:22:18 which is near the end of the movie. The piece is played by Martha Argerich.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwiIqNjlfgU

Comment: Sounds like might be Chopin.

Answer (score 3):

It's the second movement of Ravel's Piano Concerto in G; [here's another recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF9R4oPyy5c) of her playing it.